# What is the Linux equivalent to MSVC++'s option /d1reportSingleClassLayout?

Tags: linux, c++

I am moving development to Linux but I couldn't find how I can get an output similar to /d1reportSingleClassLayout from MSVC++ under g++ or clang++. If these compiler do not have such a feature, is there an external tool that provides similar visualization?

Comment: You'd be better off asking this on stack overflow, since this is really more a C++ question than anything else; particular compiler features like this are not very relevant to the OS the compiler is running on.

Comment: Yep, caught the edit inside 5 min ;) Thx.  I've flagged it too.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses! I thought since I want a linux solution it would be appropriate here. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 8):

You need to compile the file with debugging information (`-g` option) then use `pahole` to display the struct layout.  `pahole` is usually available from the `dwarves` package ([source](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/devel/pahole/pahole.git/); [on GitHub](https://github.com/acmel/dwarves); [in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/dwarves)).

```
$ g++ -ggdb -c -o myfile.o myfile.cpp
$ pahole -C MyClass myfile.o
class MyClass {
public:

    int ()(void) * *           _vptr.MyClass;        /*     0     4 */
    int                        i;                    /*     4     4 */
    const char  *              c;                    /*     8     4 */
    void MyClass(class MyClass *, const class MyClass  &);

    void MyClass(class MyClass *);

    virtual void ~MyClass(class MyClass *, int);


    /* size: 12, cachelines: 1, members: 3 */
    /* last cacheline: 12 bytes */
};
```

The `-C` option lets you select which class/struct to examine.

If you don't have access to `pahole` you can get the same information in a much less readable form from `readelf -wi myfile.o` or `eu-readelf -winfo myfile.o`.  The paper https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2007/ols2007v2-pages-35-44.pdf describes `pahole` alongside other `dwarves` tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it [with the Clang frontend](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/12/17/dumping-a-c-objects-memory-layout-with-clang/).

Answer (score 0):

How about `-fdump-class-hierarchy` supported by g++?

- [Is there any g++ option to dump class layout and vtables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549618/is-there-any-g-option-to-dump-class-layout-and-vtables)